# How to run python script with Automator to see debug/error messages?

Tags: python, shell, terminal, automator

Currently if I use `Run shell script` and start python script there:

```
/usr/bin/python /Users/myuser/script.py "$1"
```

In case script execution fails due to exception happened, Automator returns the error, which says nothing:

```
Run Shell Script failed - 1 error
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Is there any way to run the shell script to see all debug message (or, to run Terminal and run python script there)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best way forward is to use the Python debugger with:

```
import pdb

pdb.set_trace()
```

inside your py script.

More information here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 0):

When an error occurs, program execution stops and output is overwritten with an abbreviated version of the error (which provides no useful information).

For example, running the buggy code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/6083675) will only show you this:

[image: 1 error on line 2]

You need to catch all errors to prevent that from happening.

Use `try: ... except`:

```
try:
    l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9]]
    reduce(lambda x, y: x.extend(y), l)
except Exception as error:
    print(repr(error))
```

You will get this printed out:

> AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extend'",)

If you want more information, you can just tweak the code:

```
from sys import exc_info
from traceback import extract_tb
try:
    l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9]]
    reduce(lambda x, y: x.extend(y), l)
except Exception as error:
    print(repr(error))
    print("Line number: ", extract_tb(exc_info()[2])[0][1])
```

Prints:

> AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extend'",)
>   ('Line number: ', 5)